# kafka restart after changing retention time

Tags: apache-kafka

Is it required to restart Kafka server after changing the retention time at topic level.

I have changed the Kafka retention time at topic level. So , the changes to reflect , is it required to restart kafka service

Answer (score 1):

No you do not need to restart your cluster after updating a topic retention settings.

All of the [topics configurations](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs) can be changed at runtime.

On the other hand, only some of the [broker configurations](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#dynamicbrokerconfigs) can be changed at runtime.